Favard's Theorem with Riemann-Stieltjes integrals
Given a sequence of polynomials $P_{i}(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$, though this question can probably be readily generalized, is there a way to find the weight function $f(x)$ that makes the sequence of polynomials into an orthogonal basis:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{a}^{b} P_{i}(x) P_{j}(x) f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \lambda_{i} \delta_{i j}
\end{equation*}
for a given interval $[a,b] \in \mathbb{R}$? I swear this should have a simple answer, since this is just the functional analytic version of trying to find a matrix $M$ such that $O M O^{T} = D$, but I just can't piece things together. I have a guess that it has to do with the generating function associated with the polynomials sequences, given the ones for the Legendre, Hermite, and Laguerre polynomials seem very similar to their weight function $f(x)$.
This question might also be related to Diagonalization of Integral Kernel.
EDIT: Having been informed about Favard's Theorem, my question can now be more precisely stated as:
Is there a statement of Favard's Theorem using Riemann-Stieltjes integrals, with an explicit construction of the differential function $\mathrm{d}g(x)$?

You certainly need some more assumptions for this to be possible.  Most obviously, the polynomials $P_i(x)$ must be linearly independent.

I assumed that was obvious, but yeah. But beyond that, it’s not clear to me what other conditions you’d need on the polynomials.

I’m guessing you’re working with a non-negative weight. Then, for example, polynomials satisfying this orthogonality must have their roots in [a,b] and must satisfy a three-term recurrence relation. One consequence of the recurrence relation is that the zeros of consecutive polynomials interlace. Actually, the recurrence relation turns out to be enough to give you a measure; look up Favard’s theorem. If you want the measure to be of the form f(x)dx, that’s probably more subtle.

@Beans Thank you for that pointer. I wasn't aware, but probably should've guessed, that there would be requirements based on recurrence relations.
